# How to access the custom through model in django-taggit

Tags: django, model, tags, django-taggit

how to add extra information to the tag system or access through model in django-taggit?

My model 'Post' has an image and a TaggableManager, so that each Post (or image) can have multiple tags on it, and users can search all posts by their tags.  Now, I need to specify the position of the tagged tag on each image (similar concept that users tag a friend on a specific location on a photo).

I think I need to add extra information to the through model because the coordinates belong only to the relation of a post and tag, not to the tag itself.  Here is the model.py (simplified):

```
class TaggedPost(taggit.models.TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()

class Post(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='p/%Y/%m/%d/')
    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedPost)
```

However, I cannot access the through model via the API of TaggableManager.  Is it possible to read the data?  I don't want to build another relation or mapping table.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I asked in the Google forum of taggit but no replies.  Here is my solution at the end (might not be the best)

I build my own GenericTaggedItemBase like this:

```
class GenericPostTaggedItemBase(ItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Post', related_name='%(class)s')
    x = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    y = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then similar to TaggedItem in Taggit:

```
class PostTaggedItem(GenericPostTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Tagged Item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tagged Items")
```

In my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # whatever fields go here
    tags = TaggableManager(through=PostTaggedItem)
```

To assess the data:

```
Post post = Post.objects.get(pk=1)
models = post.posttaggeditem.all()
for item in models:
    # here is item.x and item.y
```

The key here is the `related_name` in `GenericPostTaggedItemBase`.  It must be `%(class)s` or similar (see the source in taggit).  So that the generic base can be used with other type of tags, if you have.  Also, this is kind of 'recommended' for abstract class (don't use fixed related_name for abstract class).  For details, search about related_name and %(class).  I will skip this here.

If you have any ideas or suggestions, please let me know.